# Check if a condition is false

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, conditional-statements

It is seems to be an easy question, I wonder why googling didn't give anything helpful -- nor in StackOverflow, nor in tutorials. I just need to check using bash that a condition is false.

Of what I found I tried

```
if ! [ 0==2 ]; then echo Hello; fi
```

and

```
if [ ! 0==2 ]; then echo Hello; fi
```

none of them print *Hello*.

I found only two similar questions, but the end answer in both cases was restructured code to not use the "false" condition.

Comment: I suggest you read the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

Comment: `[ 0 != 2 ] && echo "hello"` makes it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the `test` is a whole separate command. What the difference between the `test` and `if`, such, that I should use the `test` instead?

Comment: If you check the linked manual page, you will see that `[` is an alias for the `test` command. In fact, the `if` command just checks the result of another command, in this case the `test` command. It might all be handled internally by the shells these days, but you should see `if` as just a normal command, which in turn calls another command.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just found the next remark "! EXPRESSION
              EXPRESSION is false", so the `if [ ! 0==2 ]; then echo Hello; fi` should have worked fine! What is the problem?

Comment: `==` is not the same as `=`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm sorry, that was a typo. In comment I mean.

Comment: I disagree with Joachim's suggestion to view `if` as a command.  `if` is a keyword in the grammar of the shell which introduces a conditional clause.  It is emphatically *not* a command.  At some point, someone thought it would be a good idea to introduce the command `[` so that `if [ ...` would appear to be two grammatical symbols in the shell, but `[` is *not* part of the shell grammar.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
if ! [ 0 == 2 ]; then
  echo Hello;
fi
```

You lacked space around the equality operator.

This might be the time to read http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html - especially the sections about if then else and operators. I usually have this open when I am writing scripts..

Comment: Yes, that work! Please, can you add a little explanation to the answer, why the `!` in my case didn't work? I.e. this command `if [ 0==0 ]; then echo Hello; fi` workd fine, so what the reason?

Comment: Yes... You are right, the problem was the space... Hm... But why then the `if [ 0==0 ]; then echo Hello; fi` worked?

Comment: This is legacy shell syntax and it is brittle with regards to whitespace. No reason to use nowadays.

Comment: @YagamyLight Probably because the `test` operator  `[ ... ]` check for an expression. The `0==0` is not an operation but an expression. Try to do `[ gfhjg ]; echo $?` and it will answer with 0 (-> true) as if you write `[ 1 == 1 ]; echo $?`, meanwhile if you write `[ 1 == 2 ]; echo $?` it will answer 1 (-> false)

Comment: @Maxim There are very good reasons to use `[` and `test`, namely that they are standard.  According to the shell standard, the use of `[[` produces unspecified results.  If you want your users to have the flexibility to use a better, smaller, faster shell (eg, be able to use the right tool for whatever application they happen to be using), shell scripts must not use `[[`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell _If you want your users to have the flexibility to use a better, smaller, faster shell_ - this is a bash-specific question. I normally stick `#!/bin/bash` she-bang because I don't test my scripts with any other shells. Of course, in `autoconf` world your comment would make sense.

Comment: This question is tagged 'shell', and readers finding this question through that link will not expect bash specific answers.  Comments recommending use of non-standard shell extensions should clearly specify that the recommendation is non-standard.   There is a world of difference between 'legacy' and 'standard'.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Never mind the question has got BASH in its title and tagged bash )

Comment: @maxim Never mind that the question is tagged 'shell' and is about a very common shell construct.  Why do want to perpetuate ignorance?  'non-bash' is not the same as 'legacy'.  Developer ignorance of bashisms is a major problem; why do you object to me pointing out that you are recommending a bashism as if it is standard?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Because ignorance is bliss and portability by adhering to stone-age tools is expensive. I suggest you complain to bash developers to remove non-POSIX shell extensions. And to developers of better shells.

Answer (score 10):

For mathematical evaluations use `((  ))` in bash. For text use `[[ ]]`.

```
if (( $i == 0 )); then
  echo "i is 0"
else
  echo "i is unequal 0"
```

[Read more here about comparison operators in bash.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

[And more on double parenthesis](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to bash's mathematical evaluations, you can use boolean expressions instead of `if`:

```
[max@localhost:~] $ (( 0 == 0 )) && echo True || echo False
True
[max@localhost:~] $ (( 0 != 0 )) && echo True || echo False
False
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the `test` command (`[..]`) you can use the comparison option for integer: `-eq`, equal, and `-ne`, not equal.

```
if [ 0 -eq 2 ]; then echo true ; else echo false ; fi # false
if [ 0 -eq 0 ]; then echo true ; else echo false ; fi # true

if [ 0 -ne 2 ]; then echo true ; else echo false ; fi # true
if [ 0 -ne 0 ]; then echo true ; else echo false ; fi # false
```

---

In bash the operator `[...]` is the equivalent of `test`, a command that checks file types and compare values; test is an internal command: if you ask to your shell with `type [` it will answer `[ is a built in shell command`. You can find the binary too usually in `/usr/bin/[`.

The SYNOPSIS is `test EXPRESSION`, as you can read from `man test` or from `info coreutils test invocation`.

> An omitted EXPRESSION defaults to false.  Otherwise, EXPRESSION is true or false and sets exit status.

This is an excerpt from man that cam help to understand a little better

- **( EXPRESSION )**   EXPRESSION is true.  So it's easy to incur in the error to consider as an operation `0==1`. (The operation is `0 == 1` with spaces, `0==1` is an expression).
- **! EXPRESSION**  EXPRESSION is false.
- ...
- **INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2**  INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2
- **INTEGER1 -ne INTEGER2**  INTEGER1 is NOT equal to INTEGER2

From `info coreutils test invocation` you can read about the exit status of test.

> Exit status:

```
 0 if the expression is true,
 1 if the expression is false,
 2 if an error occurred.
```